# Swift: how to skip unused closure arguments

Tags: swift

Given a function signature:

```
func myFunc(someClosure: (argA: TypeA!, argB: TypeB!) -> Void)
```

sometimes I don't need the passed parameters to the closure so the call is:

```
myFunc { (_,_) in  
    //bla bla
}
```

is there a way to skip this redundant `(_,_) in` part?

Comment: You can't skip it, but you can replace it with `_ in`.

Comment: Thanks @TimVermeulen :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to skip it entirely, but if you won't use either argument, you can use

```
myFunc { _ in
    // do stuff
}
```

Similarly, if you only need one of the arguments, you can use

```
myFunc { _, something in
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Tim :) , I wish if they allow skipping unused arguments in the following swift versions.

Comment: I don't think they will for multi-line closures. For single-line closures, you can omit the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't like turning parameters into `( _ )`, so I use `( _ paramName )` (Swift 3, Xcode 8.3 beta)