# Closure Without Parameters Result in "Type of Expression is Ambiguous without a Type Annotation" Error

Tags: swift, closures

Background: complete Swift/iOS development noob.

Trying to resolve errors after upgrading an old project from 10 to 12 and I encountered "Cannot infer type of closure parameter 'view' without a type annotation" error for the following:

```
willShowLeftView = { [weak self] (controller, view) in
  self?.isLeftViewSwipeGestureEnabled = true
}
```

Since neither `controller` nor `view` is used within the closure, I assume that it is valid to remove the closure parameters resulting in the following:

```
willShowLeftView = { [weak self] in
  self?.isLeftViewSwipeGestureEnabled = true
}
```

From my limited knowledge of closures and use `weak self`, ^ should be valid. Except I am getting the "Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation" error, but I am not sure why.

Comment: `[weak self] _, _ in`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: how to skip unused closure arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387860/swift-how-to-skip-unused-closure-arguments)

Comment: Thank you @Larme - wasn't familiar with the underscore operator. Thank you for the guidance. Please feel free to provide the answer to the question so I can mark it correct and as resolved.